# Is it possible to create a dispatch_async(dipatch_get_main_queue(), ^{}); with a completion go get when the dispatch block is finished?

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, dispatch

I have a piece of code that execute a coredata update of the database, and I would like to know when that block is finished. Is there a way to get it knowing when the coredata has finished to update the tables?

Main function:

```
 NSMutableArray* responseArray = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:0 error:NULL];
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
             [self parseAndAddLovAll:responseArray toArray:self.objects];
        });
```

Function used in dispatch:

```
- (void)parseAndAddLovAll:(NSMutableArray*)responseArray toArray:(NSMutableArray*)destinationArray
{
    NSError *error;
    DB_ListOfValue_manage *elements_to_store = [[DB_ListOfValue_manage alloc] init];
    NSManagedObjectContext * context = [elements_to_store managedObjectContext];

    for (int index=0; index < [responseArray count]; index++)
    {
        NSDictionary * responseArray2 = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithDictionary:responseArray[index]];
        NSString * table_to_store = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:[responseArray2 objectForKey:@"table"]];

        NSArray * lignes = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:[responseArray2 objectForKey:@"lignes"], nil];
        id value;

        // Check if LOV table or contact table
        if ((([@"Table_contact" compare:table_to_store])!=NSOrderedSame)&&
            (([@"Table_event" compare:table_to_store])!=NSOrderedSame))
        {
            for (NSDictionary * item in lignes[0])
            {
                value = [item objectForKey:@"codeevent"];
                if ([value isEqualToNumber:[NSNumber numberWithInt:EVENT_ID]])
                {//FIXME: bug to check when SYNC
                    elements_to_store = (DB_ListOfValue_manage*)[NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:table_to_store inManagedObjectContext:context];
                    elements_to_store.code_event  = [value isKindOfClass:[NSNull class]] ? @"" : value;
                    value = [item objectForKey:@"id"];
                    elements_to_store.id  = [value isKindOfClass:[NSNull class]] ? @"" : value;
                    value = [item objectForKey:@"used"];
                    elements_to_store.used  = [value isKindOfClass:[NSNull class]] ? @"" : value;

                    if (![context save:&error]) {
#ifdef DEBUG
                        NSLog(@"Whoops, couldn't save: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
#endif
                    }
                    else{
#ifdef DEBUG
                        NSLog(@"Data saved to DB, table %@ %@ %@", table_to_store, elements_to_store.label1, elements_to_store.label2);
#endif
                    }
                }


            }
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: I suggest to use NSFetchedResultsController and NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate. Maybe it’s what you want

Comment: Use a diapatch_group and dispatch_group_notify